# returning multiple rows from a subquery?

Tags: mysql, sql

should i be grouping here? i want to return all the rows relating to each relationship in the first where clause but i want the rows to be grouped by station (station_id)

whats the best way to do this?- i have tried this query below but it doesnt allow for return multiple rows in the where clause subquery

```
SELECT 
    posts.dated, user_data.user_id , user_data.delegate_no, user_data.first_name, user_data.surname, user_data.company_name, user_data.tel_no, user_data.email_addr, user_data.rfid_tag 
FROM 
    user_data, posts 
WHERE 
    posts.station_id = 
        ( SELECT station_id FROM upd8r_stations WHERE owner_id =  '12' ) 
    AND 
        user_data.user_id = posts.user_id 
ORDER BY posts.dated DESC;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use IN?

```
WHERE 
    posts.station_id IN 
        ( SELECT station_id FROM upd8r_stations WHERE owner_id =  '12' )
```